# Can not get any results back for any query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

So I am really new to this SFMC platform, but not salesforce, nor SQL. I have a query that should return all subscribers, just for a test. No matter what I do, or what query I write, I get nothing back. 0 records every time. I first started with this query:

```
select 
c.subscriberid
, c.subscriberKey
, s.EmailAddress
, c.EventDate 
from _Subscribers as s 
left join _Click as c on (c.subscriberId = s.subscriberId) 
left join _Open as o on (o.subscriberId = s.subscriberId) 
where     
o.eventDate > '2016-07-01' 
AND c.eventDate > '2016-07-01'
```

I got nothing back, so then I tried to make a simple query that would have to return something. So I ran this:

```
SELECT top 5 subscriberKey, subscriberId, EmailAddress from _subscribers
```

I even tried this:

```
SELECT subscriberKey, subscriberId, EmailAddress from _subscribers
```

And still, in my data extensions, I get nothing back. Syntax validates, data extension validates, but 0 records. Can anyone direct me as to what I am doing wrong here? Seems pretty simple, but nothing I have tried works. At all. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

If you're executing the query from an Enterprise 2.0 child business unit, then you'll need to prefix `_subscribers` with `ent.`:

```
select 
c.subscriberid
, c.subscriberKey
, s.EmailAddress
, c.EventDate 
from ent._Subscribers as s 
left join _Click as c on (c.subscriberId = s.subscriberId) 
left join _Open as o on (o.subscriberId = s.subscriberId) 
where     
o.eventDate > '2016-07-01' 
AND c.eventDate > '2016-07-01'
```

In an E2.0 account, subscribers are shared across all business units.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but every time I put the ent in front of subscribers, it throws an error: The 'Ent.' prefix can only be used to query data in a parent account from a child account.

Comment: Does the query run successfully if you run it from a Program or Automation?

Comment: I've only tried running it in the query builder in the gui. Ive been tasked with just running a specific query, but when I access the data extension to see the results, it's always 0.

Comment: Run it in an automation to ensure it's not erroring out behind the scenes.  could be a problem with the primary key or field precision in your target data extension.